# Changing boolean value in SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query, which spits out that I have an error in syntax. I cannot for the life of me understand what it is. I have a table, where one column is email and the other is subscribed (the latter of which is a boolean using tinyint). Any idea what's wrong with this syntax?

```
$query = "UPDATE $DB_TABLE SET $DB_IS_SUBSCRIBED_KEY = 0 WHERE $DB_EMAIL_KEY = $email";
```

Comment: what do you see if you display the value of `$query` before issuing the query? Is it a valid SQL statement?  (Somebody else can hassle you about SQL injection risks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your email value needs to be wrapped in quotes.

```
UPDATE tablename SET columname = 1 WHERE emailcolumn = "email@email.com"
```